# Notes and Attachments

Tags: custom-object

while creating the new custom object, we have the option checkbox for adding Notes and Attachments for new custom object

If a custom object is created, is it possible to add the Notes and attachments for the Custom object,If possible Please anyone suggest answer for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can go into the page layout and add Notes and Attachments later. The new object creation wizard simply provides a way to do this while creating the object.